# NodeMCU GET request returns nothing

Tags: lua, nodemcu

i've create a nodejs server on codespaces, just return your request type (GET or POST). but it works through microsoft edge and postman, on NodeMCU it returns nothing

it should return this:

```json
200 {"data": "get"}
```

but now it dosen't show anything, even error, this is my nodejs server code

```js
const http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    toGet(req, res);
  }
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    toPost(req, res);
  }
}).listen(8080);

function toGet(req, res) {
  res.write("{\"method\": \"get\"}");
  res.end();
}

function toPost(req, res) {
  res.write("{\"method\": \"post\"}");
  res.end();
}
```

and this is my NodeMCU init.lua file

```lua
-- somecode

http.get(ip, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
        print("failed")
    else
        print(code, data)
    end
end)

print("finished")

-- somecode
```

Comment: Please share a link to your server instance for anyone who would like to reproduce this (the code itself isn't so relevant). Even more important, share your `init.lua` that contains all relevant pieces for us to reproduce.

Comment: actually, that's all, i deployed a local node.js server just for return request method, and i tried in github codespaces too, but only postman mock server succeed.